# Attribute error while creating web page with justpy

Tags: python-3.6, justpy

Hi I was creating a simple plain web page with justpy and I got an attribute error.

This was the code:

```
import justpy as jp

def app():
    wp = jp.WebPage()  
    return wp

jp.justpy(app)
```

this was the error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/justpy
Module directory: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/justpy, Application directory: /home/nsu/Desktop/datavisual
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Web_App_1.py", line 7, in <module>
    jp.justpy(app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/justpy/justpy.py", line 383, in justpy
    uvicorn.run(app, host=host, port=port, log_level=UVICORN_LOGGING_LEVEL)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 461, in run
    server.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 67, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'run'
```

I tried to replace `jp.WebPage()` with `jp.QuasarPage()` but got the same error

pls help.

Comment: I think you need at least python 3.7 for the latest versions. This code will definitely work with 3.8+. An older version of justpy might work if you cannot upgrade python

Comment: i guess so........................

Comment: you can't have an empty jp.WebPage(). See http://jpdemo.bitplan.com/ for some working demos